# Regarding Visual Studio (fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64')

Tags: visual-studio-2013, subroutine, abaqus

i am trying to use to user subroutines in Abaqus 6.14-2 version Software. For that i configured it by installing VS 2013 update 5 community version and Intel Parallel studio update 6 and it has passed the verification test in Abaqus.

But when i run my job, i get the following error : MSVCRT.lib(chkstk.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do. The standard pipeline is to 1) prepare a pythone subroutine in any code or text redactor; 2) launch this subroutine using Abaqus python interpreter (inside the CAE by "run script" or through the command line). What do you mean under "it has passed the verification test in Abaqus"?

Comment: By Verification i think it means that Abaqus can interact with Visual and Parallel Studio, since subroutine files are coded in Fortran, these two are required for linking and compiling. The issue has been resolved now. i added "$(VCInstallDir)\bin\x86_amd64" this entry in the visual studio>>tools>>options>>Intel Compilers and tools>>Compilers. Then above mentioned entry was added as a first input in the Executables and Library option. Actually my subroutine is coded in Fortan.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to use a library (obj file) which has been compiled as X86 module, but your project is targeted for 64bit OS. Consider switching target of your project to X64, in build settings. Or rebuilding used library for x64, if possible.

Comment: Hey, the issue has been resolved now. i added "$(VCInstallDir)\bin\x86_amd64" this entry in the visual studio>>tools>>options>>Intel Compilers and tools>>Compilers. Then above mentioned entry was added as a first input in the Executables and Library option. Actually my subroutine is coded in Fortan.